# Trigger to disable and enable button

Tags: wpf, button, triggers, styles

I have a list of items in WPF datagrid. As source I use ObservableCollection. One of the column is also checkbox binding to the bool property of collection. In the same window, out of the grid, I have also a button. I want the button to be disabled if there is no record with the checkbox checked = all items have the bool property set as false.

I think it wouldnt be any problem to do that in codebehind but I am trying do it in more wpf way using styles, triggers etc. But I dont know how to do this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the MVVM approach, which involves creating a `Command` which is DataBound to the `Button`.  If you're not already using an MVVM framework, there are several out there.

In Prism (one possibility)  The `DelegateCommand` has a `CanExecute` delegate which you can implement.  This `CanExecute` method would then evaluate your `ObservableCollection` of items and decide whether or not the `Command` can be executed (enabled) or not (disabled).  If this method returns false, the button will be disabled.

All other MVVM frameworks will have a similar `Command` construct.

There is great documentation of this and other MVVM-related activities in the Prism Documentation.  The Command-specific documentation and examples can be found [here](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/11/04/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-6-commands.aspx).